# Ring having no nilpotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, nilpotence, algebras

Consider the ring $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$, where $I=(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2)$. I want to understand for what $n$ does this ring contain no nilpotents (i.e., for what $n$ is this algebra reduced).

I have no idea how to approach this problem. If $f+I$ is a nilpotent then $(f+I)^k=I$, but how to deduce the information about $n$ from here?..

Comment: For instance, for $n = 1$, $x_1 + I$ is nilpotent.

Comment: For all $n>1$ your ring is reduced. The case $n=2$ is simple, and for $n>2$ the generator of $I$ is an irreducible polynomial.

Answer (score -1):

the algebra $k[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ is reduced if and only if $I$ is a radical ideal. this from "Elementray algebraic geometry" Klaus Hulek, page 39

Comment: Great answer! (-1)